# Вставка картинки из PHP скрипта в HTML

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте! У меня DLE. Есть HTML страница и PHP скрипт. В PHP-скрипте делается изображение:

```
$skin = '<img src="skin2d.php?skinpath='.$username.'" />';
$cloak = '<img src="skin2d.php?skinpath='.$username.'&mode=2" />';
```

Мне нужно вывести эти изображения в HTML-e. HTML в формате tpl.
Как-то так:

Как делает это ДЛЕ:
profile.tpl:

```
<img src="{foto}">
```

profile.php

```
$tpl->set( '{foto}', "{THEME}/dleimages/noavatar.png" );
```

Но, у него уже готовые картинки, а не через скрипт

Answer (score 1):

Оставьте только

```
$skin = 'skin2d.php?skinpath='.$username;
$cloak = 'skin2d.php?skinpath='.$username.'&mode=2';
```

И в profile.php

```
$tpl->set( '{foto}', $cloak );
```

Не знаю, правда, что это за картинки из файла skin2d.php выходят.